# Spring Webflow : Receiving null pointer exception when attempting to add a new view

Tags: spring, jsp, jakarta-ee, cas

Here is the view that I wish to reference registerViewTwo.jsp

```
<%@page import="java.util.Calendar"%>
<%@page import="net.tanesha.recaptcha.ReCaptcha"%>
<%@page import="net.tanesha.recaptcha.ReCaptchaFactory"%>
<%@page import="com.ewusu.util.Props"%>
<head>
    <title>Register</title>
</head>

<jsp:directive.include file="includes/top.jsp" />
<form:form method="post" id="fm1" cssClass="fm-v clearfix" commandName="${commandName}" htmlEscape="true">

<table style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 20px;"> 
    <tr><td>First Name:</td><td>    <form:input cssClass="required" cssErrorClass="error" id="firstname" size="50" 
        path="firstname" autocomplete="false" htmlEscape="true" /></td> <td><form:errors path="firstname" cssClass="errors" /></td> </tr> 
    <tr> <td>Last Name:</td> <td><form:input cssClass="required" cssErrorClass="error" id="lastname" size="50" 
        path="lastname" autocomplete="false" htmlEscape="true" /></td> <td><form:errors path="lastname" cssClass="errors" /></td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>Email:</td> <td><form:input cssClass="required" cssErrorClass="error" id="emailaddress" size="50" 
        path="emailaddress" autocomplete="false" htmlEscape="true" /></td> <td><form:errors path="emailaddress" cssClass="errors" /></td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>Password:</td> <td><form:password cssClass="required" cssErrorClass="error" id="password" size="50" 
        path="password" autocomplete="false" htmlEscape="true" /></td> <td><form:errors path="password" cssClass="errors" /></td> </tr>

    <tr> <td>Gender:</td> 
    <td><form:select path="gender">
        <form:option value="NONE" label="- Select Gender -"/>
        <form:option value="Male" label="Male"/>
        <form:option value="Female" label="Female"/>
    </form:select></td>
     <td><form:errors path="gender" cssClass="errors" /></td> </tr>

    <tr> <td>Birthday:</td>
        <td><form:select path="day">
            <form:option value="0" label="- Day: -"/>
            <% for(int i = 1; i <= 31; i++) { %>
                <form:option value="<%=i %>" label="<%=String.valueOf(i) %>"/>
            <% }%> 
        </form:select>
        <form:select path="month">
            <form:option value="0" label="- Month: -"/>
                <% 
                    String[] months = new String[] {
                        "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
                    };

                    for(int i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {

                %>  
                    <form:option value="<%=i+1 %>" label="<%=months[i] %>"/>
                <% } %>
        </form:select>
        <form:select path="year">
            <form:option value="0" label="- Year: -"/>
            <% 
                int year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) - 5;//seriously how many 5 yrs olds use the net?!?
                int minYear = year - 90; //sure 80 year olds have better things to do with their time
                for(; year >= minYear; year--) {
            %>      
                <form:option value="<%=year %>" label="<%=String.valueOf(year) %>"/>
            <% } %>
        </form:select></td> 
        <td><form:errors path="day" cssClass="errors" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr> <td>Remember me:</td>
        <td><form:checkbox path="rememberLogin" value="1"/></td>
        <td><form:errors path="rememberLogin" cssClass="errors" /></td>
    </tr> 
</table>

<%
   ReCaptcha c = ReCaptchaFactory.newReCaptcha(Props.PUBLIC_RECAPTCHA_KEY, Props.PRIVATE_RECAPTCHA_KEY, false);
   out.print(c.createRecaptchaHtml(null, null));
%>          
    <form:errors path="recaptcha" cssClass="errors"/>
<div> 
    <span style="padding-right: 10"> <input class="btn-submit" type="submit" name="_eventId_submit" value="submit" /> </span> 
    <span> <input class="btn-submit" type="submit" name="_eventId_cancel" value="cancel"/> </span> 
</div>  

    <input type="hidden" name="lt" value="${flowExecutionKey}" />

</form:form>

<jsp:directive.include file="includes/bottom.jsp" />
```

Here is the web.xml file cas servlet mapping

```
    **<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>cas</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/register</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!--  Added reguser servlet mapping 4th May 2014 -->

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>cas</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/reguser</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>**

    <!-- Section removed to fit Stackoverflow -->

    <session-config>
        <!-- Default to 5 minute session timeouts -->
        <session-timeout>5</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
```

Here is a snippet from my cas-servlet.xml file which maps the url reguser to the webflow registertwo-webflow.xml

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter"
        p:flowExecutor-ref="flowExecutor"
        p:flowUrlHandler-ref="flowUrlHandler" />

    <bean id="flowUrlHandler" class="org.jasig.cas.web.flow.CasDefaultFlowUrlHandler" />

    <webflow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor" flow-registry="flowRegistry">
        <webflow:flow-execution-attributes>
            <webflow:always-redirect-on-pause value="false" />
        </webflow:flow-execution-attributes>
    </webflow:flow-executor>

    <webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" flow-builder-services="builder">
        <webflow:flow-location path="/WEB-INF/login-webflow.xml" id="login" />
        <webflow:flow-location path="/WEB-INF/remind-webflow.xml" id="remind" />
        <webflow:flow-location path="/WEB-INF/register-webflow.xml" id="register" />
        <!--  Added new register for Customer and Spec 4th May 2014 -->
        **<webflow:flow-location path="/WEB-INF/registertwo-webflow.xml" id="reguser" />**
        <webflow:flow-location path="/WEB-INF/update-webflow.xml" id="update" />
    </webflow:flow-registry>
```

Here is my webflow xml file registertwo-webflow.xml and I am trying to call registerViewTwo.jsp in the second to last line shown in this file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">

    <on-start>
        <evaluate expression="initialFlowSetupAction" />
    </on-start>

    <!-- VIEW STATES -->
    <view-state id="register" view="registerViewTwo" model="customer">
    <!-- <var name="customer" class="com.ewusu.model.Customer"/>  -->
```

I am trying to call the registerTwoView.jsp in the registertwo-webflow register state, but when I start the Tomcat webserver and try to access the relevant URL, I receive a null pointer exception (see below)

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [cas] in context with path [/sso] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.webflow.execution.FlowExecutionException: Exception thrown in state 'register' of flow 'reguser'] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.ServletMvcView.doRender(ServletMvcView.java:50)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.AbstractMvcView.render(AbstractMvcView.java:180)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.render(ViewState.java:314)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.doEnter(ViewState.java:208)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.start(Flow.java:535)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.start(FlowExecutionImpl.java:364)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.start
```

The strange thing is that the existing registerView.jsp can be accessed using the registertwo-webflow.xml file just fine.  I hope I have provided enough information as I cannot understand what is wrong

Comment: Too much code.  Can you localize where the problem is happening? I'm not sure if people will be inclined to answer based on the volume of content you have shown.

Comment: I have reduced the amount of code in the question as helpfully redirected.  The core of the problem is attempting to call view registerViewTwo in my registertwo-webflow.xml webflow file